# How to Audit Spring data jpa @Query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

To Audit log all the DB changes , we have implemented Hibernate `Interceptor(org.hibernate.Interceptor)` .
We can able to log the audit for the query executed using JpaRepository

Interceptor We have used- Sample

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.hibernate.CallbackException;
import org.hibernate.EntityMode;
import org.hibernate.Interceptor;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

public class TestInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public boolean onLoad(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,
        String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onCollectionRecreate(Object collection, Serializable key) throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onCollectionRemove(Object collection, Serializable key) throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onCollectionUpdate(Object collection, Serializable key) throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void preFlush(Iterator entities) throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void postFlush(Iterator entities) throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Boolean isTransient(Object entity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int[] findDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,
        String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object instantiate(String entityName, EntityMode entityMode, Serializable id) throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getEntityName(Object object) throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getEntity(String entityName, Serializable id) throws CallbackException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void afterTransactionBegin(Transaction tx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

But if we run the query via `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` that interceptor is not getting called.

Is this possible to Audit/Intercept the Query Executed using `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`

i.e I have the following Query in my Repository, this is not triggering Hibernate Interceptor

```
  @Transactional
  @Modifying
  @Query("DELETE from MyEntity my where my.id =?1")
  void deleteById(Long id);
```

Comment: Hibernate interceptors only work for entities NOT queries. This has nothing to do with Spring Data JPA but with how interceptors work. The same would happen if you use the the `EntityManager` directly.

Comment: Can you show your Interceptor. I do the same with JPA EntityListeners and there also with this query the Listener is called.

Comment: @ Simon Martinelli  i have updated

Comment: @ Simon Martinelli  I tried JPA EntityListeners also, still the direct query using spring @Query is not called the listeners

Comment: I created a small demo project for your convenience that works: https://github.com/simasch/bulk-delete Please check if you find any difference.

Comment: ok thanks lot :)  i will try.. , and is that worked for you??

Comment: @ Simon Martinelli  I have tried that. it did not  worked! :(

Answer (score 1):

To intercept spring data queries add this prop:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session_factory.interceptor=com.yourpacakge.TestInterceptor

I used an interceptor class that extends from EmptyInterceptor just for simplicity.

```
public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        System.out.println("Query intercepted: " + sql);
        return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
    }
}
```

DOCS: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-session-events