# How to log jpa query with custom message?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, log4j2

I've a project with spring-data-jpa 2.0.5.RELEASE. I need to log in a file every query executed (`insert`, `update`, `delete`, `select`) with parameters and other info. I found that you can enable Hibernate to log queries and params but they are not in the format that I need.

Right now it prints something like this:
- (info) Hibernate: select * from table a where a.x= ?
- (info) binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - com.mypackage.foo

I want something like:
- (debug) User Mickey Mouse ask for Select *  from table a where a.x= ? [com.mypackage.foo]

Is there a way to do something similar?
I tried using aop but I've problem to find the pointcut and I'm not sure I've found the right method to wrap.

This is my test. (Not working)

```
@Pointcut("within(org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution+)")
    public void jpaQueryMethods() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(* execute(..))")
    public void executionMethods() {}

    @Before("jpaQueryMethods()")
    public void beforeJpaQueryExecution(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        logger.fatal(" signature->", joinPoint.getSignature().toLongString());
        if(joinPoint.getArgs()!=null) {
            for(Object arg: joinPoint.getArgs()) {
                logger.info("----------->"+String.valueOf(arg));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the binding parameters you have to set this property:

```
#Spring boot
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

you can also add custom messages:
[How to Audit Spring data jpa @Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946689/how-to-audit-spring-data-jpa-query/51950518#51950518)

Comment: Thank you! The link it helped me to writie custom message for queries! Is there a way to do the same thing with params? Also in this case i need to add more info in the log and have a more compact representation of the params.

Comment: Take a look to EmptyInterceptor.java methods, it may have what you are looking for.